# Xcode 5 - Storyboard - Has no constraints

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard

Does anyone know why I get the following message:

"The selected views have no constraints. At build time explicit left, top, width, and height constraints will be generated for the view."

[image: XCode 5 - Storyboard - Autolayout - No constraints]

I'm using XCode 5 - Storyboard with AutoLayout turned on

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Found the solution!

Select the ViewController then from the XCode menu:

Editor --> Resolve Auto Layout issues --> Add missing constraints in View Controller

[image]

Comment: From your screenshot I see that option is greyed out... Is exactly what I'm having. Any way to solve that?

Comment: Its because I selected that option before I took the screenshot

Answer (score 1):

It appears that in Xcode 5.1 when using AutoLayout, when you create a new scene it will start without any editable constraints. They are generated at runtime to reflect the scene's intended layout.

So adding constraints in interface builder is not needed only if you wish to modify the defaults. When you do that you need to familiarize yourself with the provided tools (as seen in the "Resolve auto layout Issues" menu)

In a ideal wold layout just works without thinking to constraints, even if they work behind the scenes. It seems to me a step towards that goal. This is not to start a debate if the goal can be reached, only to say that we can expect more similar interface builder / xcode changes to follow.

Answer (score 0):

You have selected auto layout on your viewcontroller , so you can't set the contraints manually , uncheck the layout , it will show the constraints automatically .

Comment: Isn't this wrong? Aren't constraints only used with Auto Layout?