# Image displaying in iOS7, but not iOS6.1

Tags: ios, ios6, uiimageview, ios7

I have a standard `UIImageView`, which I'm creating with...

```
UIImage *someImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"some_image"];
self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:someImage];
```

The image shows just fine on iOS7, but disappears on iOS6.1 (Retina 4), i.e. a blank white space is displayed instead of the image. I have two image files (non-retina and @2x) in the assets catalog, and I know they're getting loaded fine (since an image displays when I run on iOS7), so what explains their disappearance in iOS6.1?

Comment: Added, but I'm not sure it's very useful! As I said, works just fine on iOS7, but not iOS6, and I doubt this has to do with the UIImageView alloc'ing.

Comment: initWithImage takes a UIImage, not an NSString.  Is that really the code you are using?

Comment: Oops, sorry - updated. But again, this has nothing to do with how I'm loading the view, since the view loads just fine in iOS7.

Comment: Is your imageview near the bottom of the view? It might be possible that it is below the screen in ios 6 because ios 7's views go behind the navigation and status bar by default.

Comment: Nope. Slap bang in the middle of the view. No nav bars or status bars enabled either.

Comment: @user2709279 synthesize imageView..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem was with the Assets Catalog. The "Universal" (default) image set is misleading, because it doesn't appear to be actually universal. I needed to check the IB Asset Catalog option under this image for 'iPhone' as well as 'R4', and then have images generated for all sizes in each, before this problem fixed itself. Very confusing and non-intuitive.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and in my case, I figured out the problem was in the IB, I had Autosizing in the Size Inspector with all 4 corners picked.  I deselected the bottom and right one and the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

imageView is an IBOutlet ?

Why you don't use :

```
self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image_name"];
```

Comment: Sorry, misled with the code snippet. Corrected. But honestly, I don't think the problem has anything to do with how I'm creating the UIImageView - since the image **loads just fine** in iOS7, but not iOS6.

Answer (score 0):

This answer to a related question fixed it for me. Long story short: Your UIImageView is probably missing constraints.

[Xcode 5 - Storyboard - Has no constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18911986/xcode-5-storyboard-has-no-constraints)