# Failed to set label frame in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7, uilabel

The frame of the label in `tableViewCell` can not be set in the `ableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method. In fact as show in the `NSLog`, the label's frame has changed but it did not show on the view.  **I expected the label(with green background) should be taller than in the picture, which can show all the text in it**. The `Prototype Cell` with `Identifier` "cell" is created in the `storyboard`. Any help will be appreciated.

ps: Xcode 5.0.2, iOS7

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString * str = @"Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib";
    NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:str, str, str , str, str, str, nil];
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSInteger row = indexPath.row;
    CGSize sizeConstraint = CGSizeMake(tableView.frame.size.width, 2000);
    CGSize size = [[array objectAtIndex:row] boundingRectWithSize:sizeConstraint options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:FontName size:FontSize]} context:nil].size;

    return size.height + 20;
}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSInteger row = indexPath.row;
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
    label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
    label.numberOfLines = 0;
    label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:FontName size:FontSize];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    label.text = [array objectAtIndex:row];

    CGSize sizeConstraint = CGSizeMake(tableView.frame.size.width, 2000);
    CGSize size = [label.text boundingRectWithSize:sizeConstraint options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: label.font} context:nil].size;
    CGRect rect = label.frame;
    rect.size.height = size.height;
    [label setFrame:rect];
    NSLog(@"label height :%f", label.frame.size.height);
    [label sizeThatFits:sizeConstraint];
    return cell;
}
```

[image]
[image]

when you scroll the `tableView`, you can see the label in the first and second cell are well displayed now. (Here i just scrolled out the two cells and pull them back.)

[image: after scroll the tableView]

Comment: @iDev Then you can see the tableview's separator line clearly

Comment: set bound instead of frame

Comment: Why do you use `[label sizeThatFits:sizeConstraint];` after setting the frame ?

Comment: @NicolasBonnet I tried it to solve the problem, but not work.

Comment: @CoolMonster Seems not work.

Comment: if you want I have a solution using constraint but I don't know if you want use constraint... Should I made a answer with constraints?

Comment: and try : `[label setFrame:cell.frame]`

Comment: green background is actual size in table cell creation. they cell height only has different. what you want exactly

Comment: @NicolasBonnet Sure, I will up vote your answer. I appreciate if you can tell us why the codes do not work in Xcode 5 and iOS7 now, I create the project with Xcode 5.0.2.

Comment: @iDev I have updated the post, please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your post I don't find the definition of labelBible that you use to set the frame of the label.

Using constraint it's quick:

[image]

and

[image]

In this way you don't have to do anything in your `-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method.

Edit: to use constraint: `Use Autolayout` has to be checked.

[image]

Hope that will work as you want.

Comment: did you try : `[label setFrame:cell.frame]` ?

Comment: [label setFrame:cell.frame] not work. Why could not . And "The selected views have no constraints. At build time explicit left, top, width, and height constraints will be generated for the view." I can not set the constraints of the label...

Comment: I fixed my problem by uncheck the Use Autolayout property of my UILable in the storyboard.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18911986/xcode-5-storyboard-has-no-constraints this post i find the solution to add the constrains of the label.

Comment: If i uncheck the Use Autolayout, The codes in my question work great:) Thanks for your answer:)

Answer (score 0):

just uncheck the auto layout from the file inspector of the label frame.